# Limit of a seqence $\{f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of functions?

Tags: limits, functions, notation, terminology

I don't really know how mathematicians talk about this concept.
I try to explain better what I mean with limit of a sequence of functions:

Given a countable set of functions $\{f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$  and $f_i:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ I call the "limit" (probably with a wrong notation) of this functions a function  $\varphi$

1$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}f_n=\varphi$ In other words with I mean that: 
$\forall x\in\mathbb R\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=\varphi(x)$

This kind of "convergence" of function maybe doesn't make sense, because with numbers we can know two values are  getting closer, with a set of fucntions I don't know how but I can see better this concept plotting functions: for example how the set of functions $\{t_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ where [$t_n(x)=^nx$ (tetration)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTetrationConvergence2D.png) get closer to the black line and is an example of what i mean with $t_{n\to +\infty}=\varphi$

> Generalizing, what I'm intrested in is:
>
> given a set of functions
>   $\mathcal H:=\{h|h:X\rightarrow X\}$, a subset $\{f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb
> > N}\subset\mathcal H$ and $\varphi \in \mathcal H$ how can I express
>   this:
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}f_n=\varphi$$ only if  $$\forall a\in X\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}f_n(a)=\varphi(a)$$

**Questions**

> A) Is this the right notation? If not how/where(theory) can we talk
>   about this concept?
>
> B) I would like to know (if not take too much effort) if maybe which
>   extra concepts I need for generic sets of functions $\mathcal H$

thanks in advance and sorry for grammar errors.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence

Comment: When you talk about a sequence of elements of some set $X$, what you really are talking is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $X$ and the set of all such sequences/functions is usually written $\mathcal F\left(\Bbb N, X\right)$ or $X^\Bbb N$. You can't really talk about sets for sequences. From a sequence, you can get the set of all its elements but since a set isn't ordered doesn't keep count of how many of each elements there are, you can't get a sequence from a set. For example, the set $\{0,1\}$ would represent both $0,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots$ and $0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$.

Comment: @xavierm02 in other words in my case when I'm talking of $\{f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ i can write $F(n)=f_n$ with $F\in \mathcal H ^{\mathbb N}$, right?

Comment: @xavierm02 fixed $\$ $

Comment: @MphLee : Yes. Except, I wouldn't use $\{\}$ since (in my mind at least) those are for sets. I think the standard notation for sequences if what you wrote with parenthesis  instead of $\{\}$.

Comment: @xavierm02 yea, i think your right, with sequence you mean an $n$-tuple, that as you said is an element of the cartesian product of $\mathcal H \times \mathcal H \times ... \times \mathcal H$ that is the set $\mathcal H ^{\mathbb N}$. I used $\{\}$ because is the notation for an Indexed family, that is a set but as you said isn't the set of functions, yea i used wrong notation thanks.

Comment: @MphLee : Since you just called it a cartesian product, I'm not sure anymore if you understand that $\forall n \in \Bbb N, X^n \not= X^\Bbb N$. $X^\Bbb N$ isn't the first thing that comes to mind when you talk about cartesian products. It's more of a generalisation of the cartesian product.

Comment: @xavierm02 mmh. maybe I don't undertand but, since the (infinite) sequence is an ordered $n\in \mathbb N$-tuple of elements of $X$ it belongs to the cartesian product of $\displaystyle\prod_{n\in \mathbb N}X$, but you called the set of sequences on $X$, $X^\Bbb N$ so I believed was the right notation.

Comment: @MphLee : I think you understood :) Even though I don't think the word tuple is appropriate for infinitely many elements.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ok, thanks again for you answer and explainations. it helped me alot, even because now i realize i was a bit confused about the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) This concept is called "pointwise convergence" and you can read more about it on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence

B) You need some notion of convergence on your sets.  The most general setting for this is a topological space.

Comment: Thanks, is what I was looking for,but can you clarify a thing (in the most general scenario) the set $X$ must have a topologic structure, or the sect of functions $\mathcal H$?

Comment: If you are interested in pointwise convergence, then you are defining convergence on a sequence of functions by via convergence in the set $X$, so $X$ must have some topological structure.  This *induces* the topological structure on $H$.  There are other topological structures you could consider on $H$ -- look up "function space" or somesuch.